# Is there a tool in VScode to predict optimal amount of gas price?

Tags: gas, gas-price, visual-studio-code

On MetaMask, it shows you the optimal (estimated) gas price (and you can even tweak it). Is there a similar tool for VSCode (Visual studio code) as well? Below is the screenshot of MetaMask:

[image]